# JQuery UI Dialogs and divs in separate files

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I am working on a project and I'd like to use Jquery UI for some of the forms like adding and updating stuff instead of normal pages. I designed the dialog, set up the form but it works only if the form/div is in the same file as the button. I am using CodeIgniter for this project by the way.

So I have few questions:

1. Does JQuery UI dialogs support using divs from separate files? (if the button is not in the same file as the form/div)
2. If it does, how can I use a div that is in a different file (instead of placing the div in the same file with the button where I have few other components)?

Example:

### index.php

```
<body>
<input type="button" id="add_new"  value="add new" />
 </body>
```

---

### form.php

```
<body>
<div id='"new_user_form'> 
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <input type="button" id="add_user"  value="add new" />
</div> 
</body>
```

---

### custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('# add_new ').click (function ()
    {

            $("# new_user_form ").dialog
            ({

                title: 'Add new user',
                height: 400,
                width: 600,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                buttons:
                    [
                        {
                            text: 'add new',
                            id: ' add_user ',
                            click: function()
                            {
                                alert("Testing 123...");
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'cancel',
                            click: function()
                            {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }

                    ]

            })

         })

      })
```

---

thanks for reading, hope someone can help me!

Comment: HI @Ruffles, are you saying the button and form div may be in separate template files? If so it wouldnt matter as once rendered they all appear to be the same file in JavaScript's eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the load() function didn't work but I found a better way to fix this problem.

How I did it:

users_view.php (previously index.php)

```
<body>
<input type="button" id="add_new"  value="add new" />

<div id="new_user_form">
   <?php $this->load->view('add_user_form'); ?>
</div>

</body>
```

add_user_form.php (previously form.php)

```
  <div> 
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <input type="button" id="add_user"  value="add new" />
    <input type="button" id="cancel"  value="cancel" />
 </div>
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

      $("#new_user_form").dialog
      ({

              title: 'Add new userт',
              height: 400,
              width: 600,
              resizable: false,
              modal: true,
              draggable: false,
              autoOpen: false

      })

      $('#add_new').click (function ()
      {
          $("#new_user_form").dialog("open");
      })

      $('#cancel').click(function()
      {
        $("#new_user_form").dialog("close");
      });
 })
```

Thanks for the answers! I hope this will help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible, but I noticed a few errors :

- You wrote id='"new_user_form', it could make " part of the id.
- Same for this selector $('# add_new ') and $("# new_user_form "), trim it.
- You declare your .dialog() on a div that is probably not yet in the DOM, since you load it from form.php.
- do not use body in a page you will append, or you might end up with two body tags.

You could load form.php with something similar to `.load("form.php")`, you will have to remove those body tags from form.php :

```
$("body").load("form.php",function()
{
    $("#new_user_form").dialog(
    {
        // your options
    });
});
```

Or you can also declare a dialog and replace its content when you need to, you will have to remove body and div from your form.php in order to use this code :

```
<div id='new_user_form' style='display:none;'></div> <!-- somewhere in your index.php -->

// when document ready is triggered
$("#new_user_form").dialog(); 

// when you need it :
$("#new_user_form").load("form.php",function(){$("#new_user_form").dialog("open")});
```

Comment: Well I forgot to say that I am using the dynamic page where only the main content div is changing and the header and footer stay the same.

Comment: Are you also using form.php separately then? Not only in the context of a .dialog() widget?

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter so I have the form in a different view file.

Comment: It's like: the button is in users_view.php and the form is in add_user_view.php, they are in the same folder.

Comment: And what would make the above break? Except the body tags?

Comment: I am only using the form in the .dialog() widget, not as a separate form page.

Comment: In that case .load() will work, you just need to make sure your form is in the DOM before declaring a dialog from it.